# Why Unity XmlTextReader works for windows but not for mac build?

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity game which fetches data from XML files. The build works fine across windows platform whereas when I tried porting it to Mac, I am getting the following error.
XmlTextReader.Reader.Read() element did not appear.(Refer screenshot)
[image]
The weird thing is, it works fine on Unity Editor for Mac but not on the Mac build.

Is there a way by which I can get this XmlTextReader working on a mac? or suggest better alternatives?

Xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <PickStructure>
        <Picks>
            <Pick id = "0" name = "name" weight = "6" strength = "9" defense = "7" display = "5" description = "description"> </Head>
            <Pick id = "1" name = "name" weight = "7" strength = "8" defense = "7" display = "6" description = "description"> </Head>
            <Pick id = "2" name = "name" weight = "2" strength = "2" defense = "2" display = "3" description = "description"> </Head>
            <Pick id = "3" name = "name" weight = "6" strength = "3" defense = "7" display = "1" description = "description"> </Head>
            <Pick id = "4" name = "name" weight = "3" strength = "5" defense = "3" display = "2" description = "description"> </Head>
            <Pick id = "5" name = "name" weight = "6" strength = "4" defense = "7" display = "4" description = "description"> </Head>
            <Pick id = "6" name = "name" weight = "2" strength = "4" defense = "7" display = "8" description = "description"> </Head>
        </Picks>
    </PickStructure>
```

PicksReader code:

```
namespace PicksXML
{
    public interface IPicks
    {
        float GetWeight();
        float GetStrength();
        float GetDisplay();
        float GetDefense();
        string GetDescription();
    }

    //[System.Serializable]
    public class Picks : IPicks
    { 
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public uint _id;
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string _name;
        [XmlAttribute("weight")]
        public int _weight;
        [XmlAttribute("strength")]
        public int _strength;
        [XmlAttribute("display")]
        public int _display;
        [XmlAttribute("defense")]
        public int _defense;
        [XmlAttribute("description")]
        public string _description;

        public float GetWeight() { return _weight; }
        public float GetStrength() { return _strength; }
        public float GetDisplay() { return _display; }
        public float GetDefense() { return _defense; }
        public string GetDescription() { return _description; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("PickStructure")]
    public class PicksReader
    {
       [XmlArray("Picks")]
       [XmlArrayItem("Pick")]
       public Picks[] _picks;


        public void Save(string path)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PicksReader));
            using(var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
            }
        }

        public static PicksReader Load(string path)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PicksReader));
            using(var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as PicksReader;
            }
        }

        //Loads the xml directly from the given string. Useful in combination with www.text.
        public static PicksReader LoadFromText(string text) 
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PicksReader));
            return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as PicksReader;
        }

    }

}//namespace PicksXMl
```

Comment: Submit a bug report to Unity. Sounds like a real bug on MAC builds.

Comment: What is the source of the xml data? can you post it and the code snippet?

Comment: I have updated the question with XML data and the reader code.

Comment: And the encoding of the XML is actually UTF-8, right? I would wonder about the line encoding and the file encoding causing some issue between platforms.

Comment: @KSib I tried all combination of line encoding and the file encoding. It did not help.